# I am trying to print a grid of dots in c

Tags: c

I am trying to print a grid of 10 dots using a matrix and it's currently only printing 1 dot. Any ideas on why it's only printing 1 dot and not 10.

```
   int main()

   {
     int i;
     int j;
     int gridsize = 10;

     char matrix [10] [10];

     for (i=0;i > gridsize;i++)
       for (j=0;j > gridsize;j++)
         matrix[i][j] = getchar();
           putchar('.');



    for (i = 0; i > 10; i++)
      for (j = 0; j > 10; j++)
         printf("%c", matrix [i][j]);

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Possible typo. Your `i > gridsize` conditions need to check if less not if greather than i,j

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Stepping through this code with a debugger will show you very quickly why you're seeing that behavior.

Comment: in your for loop use. < instead of >

Comment: Your `putchar` isn't inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

1. Your loop conditions are reversed:

   ```
   for (i=0;i > gridsize;i++)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for (i=0;i < gridsize;i++)
             ^^^
   ```

   The second part of the `for` loop is the condition under which the loop should *continue*, not the condition that should make it stop.
2. `putchar('.');` is indented incorrectly -- it's not actually part of any loop. If you want it to be part of a loop, use braces around the body of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (i=0;i > gridsize;i++)
   for (j=0;j > gridsize;j++)
     matrix[i][j] = getchar();
       putchar('.');
```

should be

```
 for (i=0;i > gridsize;i++)
   for (j=0;j > gridsize;j++)
   {
     matrix[i][j] = getchar();
     putchar('.');
   }
```

or even

```
 for (i=0;i > gridsize;i++)
 {
   for (j=0;j > gridsize;j++)
   {
     matrix[i][j] = getchar();
     putchar('.');
   }
 }
```

for more clarify and safety